# Change theme in mat-icon for Outlined

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I use `<mat-icon>person</mat-icon>` and have a result:
[image]

I need the icon on theme Outlined: [image]

How do to do it ?

Importantion of the icons: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After dealing with the same issue I found that thankfully this now works...

First, add the outlined icons to your import using "|" to separate...

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then add the class to your mat-icon...

```
<mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">person</mat-icon>
```

Comment: awesomeness as an answer

Answer (score 5):

```
<mat-icon>person_outline</mat-icon>
```

https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=person_outline&icon=person_outline&style=outline.

Comment: Does this work on icons with more than two names? Example: account_circle

Comment: @ErickZanetti you'll find all the outline icons here: https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=outline

Comment: It seems to exist for only certain types of icons. (`check_circle_outline`, `delete_outline`, etc.)

Comment: @ErickZanetti They are all individual icons - the text specifies the icon name. The "_outline" text isn't a feature or option to create an outlined version of any icon. You need to use the material.io site to find the name of whatever icon you need whether it is outline or solid.